# Android Google Maps Utility - updating cluster marker position

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to update my markers positions. Currently I am removing an item and immediately adding it back with new position, but I am not sure that this is the correct approach. What I would like to do is to update this markers position to a new value without removing/adding it back. Is it possible?

I tried with the following:

```
var cluster_item = iterator.next();
var marker = dis.cluster_renderer.getMarker(cluster_item);
marker.setPosition(new dis.maps.model.LatLng( 0, 0 ));
```

.. but its like a temporary set, once I zoom out the cluster and other markers re-render and the position is set back to its original.

Current code:

```
// Updates all items
var items = dis.cluster_manager_algorithm.getItems();
var iterator = items.iterator();
//while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
if ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
    var cluster_item = iterator.next();

    dis.cluster_manager.removeItem(cluster_item);

    var item = new dis.clustering.ClusterItem({
        //rotation: marker.rotation,
        getPosition: function () {
            return new dis.maps.model.LatLng(new_position.latitude, new_position.longitude);
        },
        userData: {imei: "some_imei"}
    });
    dis.cluster_manager.addItem(item);

    // update view
    dis.cluster_manager.cluster();
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? you just want to change marker position according to new lat lng?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want

Answer (score 0):

Lets take simple example of adding marker on my position .Whenever my location changes ,marker will go on that position . -

```
 @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
           marker.setPosition(new LatLng(location.getLatitude, location.getLongitude ));
        }
```

Now wherever you are getting latlng you can just use `marker.setPosition(latlng)` .

**EDIT**
For Bulk markers use .Assume you have arraylist having LatLng `locationList<LatLng>`.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
for(int i=0 ;i<locationList.size();i++){
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(locationList.get(i))
    .title("Marker").icon());
}}
```

If you want to use **ClusterMarker** as per Requirement ,you can find simple tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering#simple).Also there is a **demo** app present [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils).

Comment: I already stated in my question, that I tried `marker.setPosition` already. It works only temporary, when the map gets zoomed out and zoomed in again, the clusters re-render these items with their original positions. I have to change this original position, not the marker temporary position.

Comment: These items are stored in Algorithm class (https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/algo/NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm.java), but I see no way to change the items position directly.

Comment: to be honest i am not getting what you want to say. "when the map gets zoomed out and zoomed in again" . marker stays on which position? .I had worked on app like Uber recently.We are using `marker.setPosition` to update Drivers position on map and it looks like a moving car on map, wether user zooms in or zooms out ,marker stays on position where it should be

Comment: Are you going it on normal marker or cluster item marker, those are 2 different things. I have no problems setting normal google maps marker position. However, google maps utils cluster item marker position update is a different story.

Comment: O! i was talking about normal marker only .. For bulk markers ... try to use this .. markerOption = new MarkerOptions().snippet("").position((new LatLng())).icon());

Comment: Problem is I don't know how/where to push/apply this markerOption

Comment: in onMapReady , inside loop where you get different latlngs

Comment: I'm talking about "on which function I plug this on" - which class provides me with a function which allows me to change `ClusterItem` position? The `ClusterItem` class only has `getPosition`, not `setPosition`

Comment: Yes, it is necessary, otherwise I wouldn't have any problems

Comment: None of your provided links show an example of changing markers position, they only set it upon adding the item to the array.